# Information about price fluctuations

Tags: wallet

I have a block chain wallet, I know that the balance will fluctuate. But I am having trouble finding on block chain is some sort of charting, or some sort of chronological logging of those fluctuations like a stock summary. Where should I look and see this?: "OK, on aug 31st it was this amount then on 2nd of september it was this amount" I have seen both sides of the fluctuation coin, I have seen my balance exceed what i put in and of course drop below what i put in, but I have no way of tracking an exact amount like a stock summary does for you giving you 1 day, 5 day, 30 day and on and on going out as far a 5 years. Does anyone know block chain wallet well enough to give me some guidance on this question?

Comment: thank you for responding i just added that to my favorites

Answer (score 2):

Use a historical price chart like https://www.coindesk.com/price/